# Book where aliens come to a school and save it

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel

they have bananas wrapped in ham & covered in cheese for lunch one day. The aliens save the school with electricity somehow.

Comment: The aliens have bananas wrapped in ham and covered in cheese? What do they save the school from?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?

Comment: @user14111 Their dietary choices.

Comment: I'm going try that for a snack next time I'm hungry, alien food!

Comment: @user14111 Bananas wrapped in ham and topped with cheese are a semi-legendary example of terrible mid-twentieth-century American cuisine.  More recently, quite a number of bloggers have tried to recreate the horrible things:  https://retrorecipe.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/ham-banana-rolls/ https://missminamurray.wordpress.com/2015/12/16/in-the-kitchen-ham-banana-rolls/ https://www.midcenturymenu.com/the-mid-century-menu-ham-banana-casserole/ Indeed, making this disgusting dish has been seen as a kind rite of passage among retro food bloggers.

Comment: @Buzz As a time-traveler from mid-20th century America, I never heard of such a thing. But what I'm wondering is what horrors the aliens were saving those schoolkids from by bring those non-kosher bananas.